# Smooth homotopy and a theorem in Lee's book

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

Suppose that $M,N$ are smooth manifolds without boundary and $F: N \rightarrow M$ is a continuous map, then we know that $F$ is homotopic to a smooth map (**Th6.26**, Lee's Smooth Manifolds),i.e there is a continuous map $G: [0,1]\times N \rightarrow M$ such that $G(0, \cdot) = F$ and $G(1, \cdot)$ is smooth.
**My question is** : Can we choose $G$ so that $G$ is smooth in $(0,1]\times N$?

**Why I came up with this** small (and trivial?) question? : I has been learning Lee's book for fun by trying to prove each Theorems in his book by myself. Then for this Theorem, I obtained the existence of such $G$ so I wanted to check if it is really right to make sure that I understand correctly most of concepts related to Smooth Manifolds.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes. It is essentially contained in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454470/smooth-extension-of-a-continuous-function-on-the-boundary-of-a-domain), you just have to modify it to work with manifolds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you have an argument for this, why not share it? This way you wouldn't require that much work on the part of the (possible) answerer.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Dear Michal, I thought about doing the same however, based on my experiences on MSE, people seem to do not like "proof-verification" type of question so I referred to not post my attempt.

Comment: It’s hard to know what techniques are used if one does not have Lee’s text at hand. Locally, convolutions wirk just fine to answer your question.